# Uploadify calling CodeIgniter controller multiple times

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, uploadify

First time here, hopefully not the last.

I'm currently developing an application based on CodeIgniter. All was well until I realised (by using CI logging) that the Uploadify script used in the page view is calling the controller multiple times.

To explain a little better...

My news controller has an edit containing this code

```
public function edit(){
    $id = (int)$this->uri->segment(4);

    if (empty($id)){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', "ID can't be empty");
        redirect('admin/news');
    }

    //article data called here and stored in $data
    $data = $this->news_model->fetch_article($id);

    $data['title'] = "News";
    $data['news_links'] = $this->news_model->get_news_links();
    $data['form_url'] = "admin/edit";
    $data['available_pages'] = $this->news_model->get_article_pages();


    $data['css'] = "/css/extra/uploadify.css";
    $data['js'] = "/js/extra/jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js";
    $data['edit'] = true;


    //set uploadify key
    $data['key'] = md5(time() . $this->session->userdata('session_id'));
    // a unique key is created, then stored in database
    // the key is then passed to the uploadify script
    // when the upload is being done it is checked with the one in the database
    // if the two match files are uploaded. This is a workaround for flash
    // session problem
    $this->news_model->set_key($data['key']);

    if($this->input->post('submit')){
        $this->save_article("update",$id);
    }


    $this->load->view("admin/news",$data);
}
```

In my view I have Uploadify called like this

```
    $('#extra_data').uploadify({
    'swf'      : '<?php echo site_url(); ?>flash/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : '<?php echo site_url(); ?>admin/uploadify',
    'multi'     : true,
    'auto'      : false,
    'fileTypeExts'     : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
    'fileTypeDesc'    : 'Images',
    'formData'      : {'key' : '<?php echo $key; ?>'},
    'onQueueComplete': function(){
        ajax_images(); //calls a function that loads uploaded image thumbnails
    }
});
```

**Edit - adding Uploadify controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Uploadify extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    // contains set_key / check_key / get_key / add_image functions
    $this->load->model('admin/news_model');
}

public function index(){
    if($this->news_model->check_key($this->input->post("key",true))){

        $this->upload_image();

    }else{
        log_message('error', "The hash key isn't correct! No upload has been done!");
    }
}

public function load_images(){
    $data = $this->news_model->get_images($this->uri->segment(4));

    foreach($data as $image){
        ?>
        <div style="background:url(<?php echo site_url(); ?>images/uploads/thumb_<?php echo $image->file; ?>) no-repeat"> 
            <a class="delete" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="remove_pic('<?php echo site_url(); ?>admin/news/remove_picture/<?php echo $image->id; ?>')"></a>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}

private function upload_image($case = "article"){
    $this->load->library("imaging");
    $this->imaging->upload($_FILES['Filedata']);

    $file_name = md5(time().$this->input->post("key"));
    $target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/uploads/";

    if ($this->imaging->uploaded){

        $this->imaging->file_new_name_body   = $file_name;
        $this->imaging->file_auto_rename      = true;
        $this->imaging->image_resize         = false;
        $this->imaging->mime_check          = true;
        $this->imaging->allowed = array('image/*');
        $this->imaging->process($target_path);

        $this->imaging->file_name_body_pre = 'thumb_';
        $this->imaging->file_new_name_body   = $file_name;
        $this->imaging->image_resize          = true;
        $this->imaging->image_ratio_crop      = true;
        $this->imaging->image_y               = 148;
        $this->imaging->image_x               = 148;
        $this->imaging->process($target_path);

        if ($this->imaging->processed) {
            $this->news_model->add_image($this->input->post("key",true),$file_name . "." . $this->imaging->file_src_name_ext);
            $handle->clean();
        } else {
            log_message('error', $this->imaging->error);
        }
    }else{
        log_message('error', $this->imaging->error);
    }

}
```

}

**Edit No2 - adding get/set/check key f-ions**

```
function set_key($key)
{

    $data['key'] = $key;

    $this->db->where('id', 1);
    $this->db->update('uploadify_key', $data);

    log_message("debug", "Uploadify key set to " . $key);
}



function get_key($id)
{

    $this->db->select('key');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('uploadify_key');

    $row = $query->row();

    return $row->key;


}

function check_key($key,$id = 1)
{

    $db_key = $this->get_key($id);

    if($key == $db_key)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}

function clear_key($id){
    $data['key'] = "";

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('uploadify_key', $data);
}

function add_image($hash, $file){
    $data['file'] = $file;
    $data['hash'] = $hash;

    $this->db->insert("images", $data);
}

function get_images($hash){
    $this->db->select("id, file");
    $return = $this->db->get_where("images",array("hash" => $hash));

    return $return->result();
}
```

And my uploadify controller has the `$key` check mentioned above and the file upload code.

*Please mind that there are 2 controllers - News and Uploadify!*

The problem is that by isolating certain parts of code I found out that the Uploadify Javascript is calling News controller again. Here's the link to log - http://pastebin.com/JkHAy5cN

The problem with that happening is that the key is being reset and the key passed to Javascript and the one stored in database don't match. I'm stumped on this one.

Any suggestions, fixes, comments are more than welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: -@MathiasBishof is your problem solved yet?

Answer (score 0):

You would not use 2 controller functions simultaneously, just one. That's not how CI works. So point your javascript to the `news/edit` controller function. In this function, you need to then include the code that does the actual upload as i'm not seeing it above. But first things first, correct your JS.

so instead of this:

```
    'uploader' : '<?php echo site_url(); ?>admin/uploadify',
```

do this:

```
    'uploader' : '<?php echo site_url(); ?>news/edit',
```

**and** add to `news/edit` your code from the `admin/uploadify` controller function.

Comment: Well, two controllers are there for a reason. As I'm using authentication I cannot use a controller that is secured by it, that's why I got another controller for the uploads as a flash uploader creates a new session for itself. I've seen the practice of another controller being used and suggested by people who use the combination of two. The uploader asynchronously sends the files to the other controller, just as I would do it with a normal form. Am I missing something here?

Comment: yes using 2 controller functions is fine, just not simultaneously. can you show in your question what's in your admin/uploadify code?

Comment: @MathiasBishof do you know how to check the `response` in Chrome Developer tools or Firebug when you click the upload button? I'd like to see what kind of PHP errors are being generated with the AJAX call. I'm having trouble understanding your routing. So it goes admin/uploadify for the AJAX upload part then admin/news after that to submit the page?

Comment: There are no actual AJAX calls as all the file processing/sending to server is handled by the flash movie. If the key is a static one and is not regenerated then no errors are generated by the script. Otherwise it just wont upload as the keys don't match. That's also an explanation for the routing - Uploadify (I'm not using Uploadifive wich is an HTML5 version of the uploader) calls the "Uploadify" controller, uploads images, stores them in the database. When the actual form is submited it calls admin/news controller and saves the form data to database.

Comment: @MathiasBishof do you know how to check the response in Chrome Developer tools or Firebug when you click the upload button? i want to know if `$key` is being returned.